# I am getting an error while programming in android: incompatible types : InboxStye cannot be converted into Style

Tags: java, android, android-studio, notifications

I was working on notification in android and while trying to create the Big view notification im getting the following error when im using NotificationCompat.Builder object and calling setStyle and passing the NotificationCompat.inboxStyle object into it.

```
Error:(50, 39) error: incompatible types: InboxStyle cannot be converted to Style
```

Here is my code:

```
Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
notification.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);     //displays the icon for the notification
NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
String[] events = new String[4];
events[0]= new String("First event");
events[1]= new String("Second event");
events[2]= new String("Third event");
events[3]= new String("Fourth event");

inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("This is a big Content Notification");
for(int i = 0; i<events.length;i++)
    inboxStyle.addLine(events[i]);
notification.setStyle(inboxStyle); //here is the error 
notification.setSound(uri);

Intent intent = new Intent();
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(uniqueID,notification.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not show your declaration of 'notification', so it is a bit hard to tell. However, all the documentations recommend to go by this form, and it works:

```
Notification notification =  mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker("title").setWhen(0)
            ...
            .setStyle(inboxStyle)
            ...                
                .build();
```